# deploying .net web app from monodevelop

Tags: .net, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, monodevelop

I have developed a .net4.5 web app on the monodevelop ide and i want to deploy it to AWS elastic beanstalk. is there anyway to do this without having to transfer all the file to a different pc running windows (im on linux)

Thanks in advance.